# nginx: try_files's last value does not work when root is variable

Tags: vue.js, nginx

I have a Vue project which use "try_files" config to avoid 404 error when refreshing a "non root" url,like this:

```
location / {
    ......
    root /web/pcResource;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

It works fine. But when I need a variable "root" value before(decided by the user agent),like this:

```
set $dir "/web/pcResource";
if ($http_user_agent ~* "(Android|iPhone|iPod|Symbian|BlackBerry|Windows Ph    one|Mobile|J2ME)") {
    set $dir "/web/mobileResource";
}
root   $dir;
location / {
    ......
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

The "/index.html" of try_files config always directs to the file in "/web/pcResource", so I get a 404 error when refreshing a "non root" url on the mobile browser.
It seems that try_files only "remember" the first value of root. When I set $dir to "/web/mobileResource" first, then setted to "/web/pcResource" if user agent is pc, there is just a opposite error: I can refresh on my mobile browser and have a 404 error on pc browser.
What is the correct config if I want to use a variable root value?

Comment: Is there a file called `/web/mobileResource/index.html`? Or do you want `/web/pcResource/index.html` used irrespective of `$dir` value?

Comment: There are both index.html file in /web/mobileResource and /web/pcResource directory. I want to use  /web/pcResource/index.html on pc browser and to use  /web/mobileResource/index.html on mobile browser. But it seems that try_files only "remember" the first value of root. When I set $dir to "/web/mobileResource" first, then setted to "/web/pcResource" if user agent is pc, there is just a 
opposite error: I  can refresh on my mobile browser and have a 404 error on pc browser @Richard Smith

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. I get consistent results when refreshing both branches of the `if` statement.

Comment: @Richard Smith I find the reason , thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The reason is I have this config :

```
location / {
    if ($http_user_agent ~* "(Android|iPhone|iPod|Symbian|BlackBerry|Windows Phone|Mobile|J2ME)") {
        access_log   /var/log/nginx/xxmobile.log;
    }
    ........
}
```

The "access_log" option can not be in "if"  scope, but this config can be reloaded without error message. So it works after removing this option.